# PHP Validating decimal numbers and converting to US currency format

Tags: php

I am working currently with PHP validation of decimal values. The function works well in determining decimals/integers from letters but my goal is to format the decimal/integer values into proper currency values such as `$0.00`.

How can I format the input value into currency format with the dollar sign such as `$0.00`?

[EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/dropdown-menu/test1.php)

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['price'])){
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $priceString = empty($price['price'])?null:trim($price['price']);
            if(!empty($priceString)) { 
         if  (preg_match('/^[+\-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$/', $price)){
             echo ('<div id="price_input"><span id="resultval">'.$price.'</span></div>');
                }
             else {
             echo ('<div id="price_input"><span id="resultval">Please input a valid decimal number.</span></div>');
                  }
    }
    else {
        echo '';
         }              
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to validate as currency or just display it?

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon I am trying to just display it

Comment: @Yan's solution is right for you then. The title of your question was a little misleading.

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon sorry about that, I change the title to better suit my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) function:

```
money_format('$%i', 5.2);
```

outputs: $5.2

EDIT:

```
if  (preg_match('/^[+\-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$/', $price)){
    echo ('<div id="price_input"><span id="resultval">'
          .money_format('$%i', $price);
          .'</span></div>');
}
```

Comment: +1 Thank you, One thing: is there away to make it out put the full currency value like `$5.20`?

Comment: If you do `money_format('$%i', '5.20');`, you should get `$5.20`.

Comment: One little issue that i am running into: If the person decides to add a dolar sign in the input field it will then return either `invalid` or `$0.00`. Any suggestion in fixing that?

Comment: Check for the existence of the dollar sign with `strpos` or remove it with `str_replace`.

Comment: thanks, i got that to work. One last thing: if I input a value `0.02` i get an error. How come? You can test it in my Example link.

Comment: Works for me. If the native function doesn't work, try this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php#89060